# How to to convert array of indexes to Mongoose documents?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of indexed document identifiers (in this case, strings) and I need to fetch each one.

```
var emails = ["jane@gmail.com", "bob@gmail.com", "george@gmail.com"]
```

For each email, I need to look up the subsequent "User" document.

I've thought of two ways to do it:

1) I could just have a function that returns the lookup promise, and then do Promise.all on the subsequent array.

2) I could create a giant $or query.

Overall, however, I feel like this is probably a common occurrence and that both of these solutions are probably suboptimal, or at the very least, a bad practice.

Tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at $in?

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

```
User.find({ email: { $in : emails } })
```

email is the property in your model and emails is the array of emails you're searching with.